# TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs

node version : 6.14.11,
Mac OS

I want to be able to use 'response from express' and 'json from body-parser' like this..
nevertheless vscode doesn’t turn on the light 'import code' what i wrote

What i said is first that i think the problem. but i can not be sure :(

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc7e3.png)

```js
import Axios from 'axios';
import { json } from 'body-parser';
import { response } from 'express';
import {React, useEffect} from 'react'
// import { FaCode } from "react-icons/fa";
import {API_URL, API_KEY} from '../../Config';

function LandingPage() {

    useEffect(()=>{
        const endpoint = `${API_URL}movie/popular?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`;

        fetch(endpoint)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => console.log(response));


        // Axios.get(endpoint) 
        // .then(response => {
        //     setMovies([...response.results])
        //     setMainMoveImage(response.results[0])
        // })
        // endpoint에 받은 값(API)을 fetch가 가져온다? 그렇게보면 될듯
        // 그 값이 response에 담긴다.  하지만 response만으로 response을 읽을 수 없기에
        // json()을 사용해줌.
    },[])


    return (
        <>
            <div style={{ width: '100%', margin: '0'}}>

                {/* Main Image */}

                <div style={{ width: '85%', margin: '1rem auto'}}>

                    <h2>Movies by latest</h2>
                    <hr />

                    {/* Movie Grid Cards */}


                </div>

                <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <button>Load More</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default LandingPage
```

Comment: It would help to get the stack of the error (filenames and line numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this problem!
i knew that vscode makes automatically import code!

so if i delete like this,, it would be great

```js
// This is what i will delete!
import { json } from 'body-parser';
import { response } from 'express';
```